# Проектирования Базы данных с нечёткими данными

Tags: mysql, mongodb, rest, express, sequelize.js

Всем привет! столкнулся с проблемой в проекте исползоваю mysql sequilize.
Модель:

```
const receptModel = sequelize.define('Recept', {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true
  },
  pill_id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    references: {
      model: Pills,
      key: 'id',
      allowNull: false
    }
  },
  patient_id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    references: {
      model: Patient,
      key: 'id',
      allowNull: false
    } 
  }, 
  doctor_id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    references: {
      model: Doctor,
      key: 'id',
      allowNull: false
    }
  },
  how_many_days: {
    type:  DataTypes.INTEGER
  },
  time: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(255)
  },
  quantity: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(255)
  },
  description: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(255)
  },
});
```

в time мне будет приходить время приема лекарств то есть **time: ['9:00', '13:00', '18:00']** а там может быть не 3 а 5 элементов **time: ['9:00', '12:00', '15:00', '18:00', '21:00']**  а может 10 думаю поняли смысл.
Вопрос в том что как мне это лучше реализовать? так как массив и json как понял не лучшая практика хранения в sql базы данных. Думаю может мне добавить еще MongoDB но будет ли это правильным подходом? Буду рад за любую помощь и идею

Comment: *так как массив и json как понял не лучшая практика хранения в sql базы данных* Это неверно - всё зависит от того, как данные используются. Если версия MySQL достаточно свежая, поддерживающая multivalued index, то вполне себе нормально (правда, придётся хранить время в числовом представлении, но MySQL нормально принимает числовые литералы аки время). А если время будет только извлекаться для конкретной записи, а не использоваться для отбора при построении отчётов, так и этого не нужно. *Думаю может мне добавить еще MongoDB* ИМХО это неоправданное усложнение будет.

Comment: то есть если использовать multi valued index у меня time field будет примерно таком формате time : [1653463581832, 1653463512314, 1653463587535] ?

Comment: Зачем? литерал времени - это число 5-6 цифр в формате HHmmss. 09:00 будет соответственно 90000.

Comment: всё понял, спасибо за помощь щас займусь)